# Windows Server 2016 Essentials & RDP/RDS

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-essentials

I have a client that needs to be upgraded to Server 2016

she only has a small office with 5 Users, for this i thought 2016 Server essentials. I want to do my homework before completing this upgrade.

My client needs to be able to provide VPN/RDP/RDS to the 5 users in the office. 
VPN is currently installed.

My thought was VPN in, RDP session and work. Since Essentials does not require user or device cals, I am wondering what is the hard limit for RDP/RDS sessions? I hope it is not 2 sessions - Can someone with Essentials 2016 confirm or deny this? If this is true, can the user limit be lifted with RDS cals?

Thank you for your help in advance it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server 2016 Essentials only allows 2 simultaneous connections, for Admin purposes only. For 5 users, you'll have to use the Standard Edition + RDS CAL for each user/device + Windows Server CAL for each user/device.
Use Server 2016 Essentials + RDS CAL won't work.